# How to run a shell command in ansible's check mode?

Tags: git, shell, ansible

In check mode, I want to display the current commit in the server. I'm using the shell command (`git rev-parse HEAD`) to register the variable and then print/debug it but ansible skips shell commands in check mode.

Is there anyway to mark a shell command as safe to run in check mode?

Or any ansible module to do what I want? I checked into git's module but it only looks like it does checkouts.

Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Starting from Ansible 2.2, [the right way to do it](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_checkmode.html#enforcing-or-preventing-check-mode-on-tasks) is to use `check_mode: no`:

```
tasks:
  - name: this task will make changes to the system even in check mode
    command: /something/to/run --even-in-check-mode
    check_mode: no
```

Comment: Wow, `check_mode: no` means yes, run this in check mode?  What does `no` mean?

Comment: @Nick "To force a task to run in check mode, even when the playbook is called without --check, set check_mode: yes." https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_checkmode.html

Comment: This solution no longer seems to work in the latest version of Ansible (2.16.4) When I add "check_mode: no" or "check_mode: false" (which seems to be what the current docs suggest)  to a "command" task, and run my playbook in check mode, I still get the message "Check mode is not supported for this task."

Answer (score 11):

Found the answer. You have to add `always_run: True` to the task.

Comment: Now that there is a better way, I think the accepted answer should be changed to the @jfrenetic one.

Comment: It is deprecated. I'm getting this, `[DEPRECATION WARNING]: always_run is deprecated. Use check_mode = no instead.. This feature will be removed in version 2.4. Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.`

Answer (score 0):

> ***How to run a `shell` command in Ansible's `check_mode`?***

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - debug:
      var: ansible_check_mode

  - name: Command with modes
    shell:
      cmd: |
        {% if not ansible_check_mode %}
        echo "Execute command"
        {% else %}
        echo "Report only"
        {% endif %}
    check_mode: false
    register: result

  - debug:
      var: result
```

called via

```bash
ansible-playbook main.yml --check
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] ***************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  ansible_check_mode: true

TASK [Command with modes] **************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ***************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  result:
    changed: true
    cmd: |-
      echo "Report only"
    delta: '0:00:00.011725'
    end: '2024-03-19 11:00:00.670009'
    failed: false
    msg: ''
    rc: 0
    start: '2024-03-19 11:00:00.658284'
    stderr: ''
    stderr_lines: []
    stdout: Report only
    stdout_lines:
    - Report only
```

otherwise called via

```bash
ansible-playbook main.yml
```

into

```yaml
TASK [debug] **************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  ansible_check_mode: false

TASK [Command with modes] *************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  result:
    changed: true
    cmd: |-
      echo "Execute command"
    delta: '0:00:00.011212'
    end: '2024-03-19 11:15:00.576193'
    failed: false
    msg: ''
    rc: 0
    start: '2024-03-19 11:15:00.564981'
    stderr: ''
    stderr_lines: []
    stdout: Execute command
    stdout_lines:
    - Execute command
```

> ***Is there any way to mark a `shell` command as safe to run in `check_mode`?***

It will depend on the command and how it becomes implemented. See in example the following advanced task

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Ensure all file permissions in a directory are '{{ mode }}' recursively
    ansible.builtin.command:
      cmd: find {{ path }} -type f -not -perm {{ mode }} -printf "%p\n" {% if not ansible_check_mode %} -exec chmod {{ mode }} {} \;{% endif %}
    vars: # "parameter" for the task
      path: '/home/ansible_user'
      mode: '0644'
    register: found_files # if there are any
    check_mode: false # in order to support ansible_check_mode on cmd
    changed_when: found_files.stdout_lines | length > 0 and not ansible_check_mode

  - name: Files {% if not ansible_check_mode %}changed{% else %}found{% endif %}
    debug:
      msg: "{{ found_files.stdout_lines }}" # or only var: found_files
    when: found_files.stdout_lines | length > 0 # otherwise skip
```

Running in `check_mode` it will only find and report files with certain properties. So by implementing such it will be possible to perform a kind of dry-run before changes. Running without `check_mode` it find and report files with certain properties and additionally change them.